# Laravel error when call another controller

Tags: laravel

I am starting with laravel, I need to send a parameter to another controller and the controller2 return the view to show param(id), both controllers are in the controller folder, but The browser show me the next error:

InvalidArgumentException
Action App\Http\Controllers\Controller2@start not defined.

Any advice

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test/{id}','Controller1@param');
```

Controller1

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Controller1 extends Controller
{
    public function param($id){

        return redirect()->action('Controller2@start',['id'=>$id]);
    }
}
```

Controller 2

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Controller2 extends Controller
{
    public function start($id){

        return view('pages.exampleController2')->with('id',$id);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no registered route that points to that method ... the only way to get into your application is with routes (they are the URLs)

Comment: so in laravel you can´t call one controller from another controller

Comment: that isn't what you are doing ... you have a route that points to one controller, that request comes in, you are then trying to return a redirect response to another route ... that is 2 separate requests  ... calling one controller from another would be you literally calling methods on the other controller from the one controller

Comment: how can call the method start from controller1 ?

Comment: you would need to get an instance of that controller (since it is a class like any other class) then call the method on it ... though usually if you need to do something like this it would be better to refactor that functionality out of that 1 controller and be able to access it from both instead

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions